# select returns the same value four times

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm developing a Stored Procedure in SQL Server 2016 SP1.

This statement returns repeated values. It repeats the same value four times:

```
Select Serial = 
    CASE al.NumberEncoding
        WHEN 3 THEN RIGHT(ex.Serial,LEN(ex.Serial)-2) 
        ELSE RIGHT(ex.Serial,LEN(ex.Serial)-18)       
    END, AggregationLevel
from ExternalCode ex, AggregationLevelConfiguration al
where ex.ProductionOrderId = 4 and 
        ex.AggregationLevel = al.AggregationLevelConfigurationId
```

I get something like this:

```
Serial   AggregationLevel
RP4X6BXC1N0RG7  1
RP4X6BXC1N0RG7  1
RP4X6BXC1N0RG7  1
RP4X6BXC1N0RG7  1
RP4X6BXC1N0RG7  1
P5KNX3KBT4997Z  1
P5KNX3KBT4997Z  1
P5KNX3KBT4997Z  1
P5KNX3KBT4997Z  1
P5KNX3KBT4997Z  1
A6GZ9E8ZFA8YMV  1
A6GZ9E8ZFA8YMV  1
A6GZ9E8ZFA8YMV  1
A6GZ9E8ZFA8YMV  1
A6GZ9E8ZFA8YMV  1
EMAMKM4356DHGV  1
EMAMKM4356DHGV  1
EMAMKM4356DHGV  1
EMAMKM4356DHGV  1
EMAMKM4356DHGV  1
WASBFP0EYDM7BM  1
WASBFP0EYDM7BM  1
WASBFP0EYDM7BM  1
WASBFP0EYDM7BM  1
WASBFP0EYDM7BM  1
```

Is there any way to avoid this repetition?

Comment: add distinct and try once in select clause

Comment: The problem appears when I add the second table, AggregationLevelConfiguration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `GROUP BY` to remove duplicates:

```
SELECT Serial, AggregationLevel
FROM (
    SELECT
        CASE al.NumberEncoding
            WHEN 3 THEN RIGHT(ex.Serial,LEN(ex.Serial)-2) 
            ELSE RIGHT(ex.Serial,LEN(ex.Serial)-18)       
        END as Serial
    ,   AggregationLevel
    FROM ExternalCode ex
    JOIN AggregationLevelConfiguration al ON ex.AggregationLevel = al.AggregationLevelConfigurationId
    WHERE ex.ProductionOrderId = 4
) nested
GROUP BY Serial, AggregationLevel
```

Comment: Note the change to ANSI join syntax, it has been "the modern way" to express joins for nearly two decades now.

Comment: plus 1 for the ansi join syntax, where do they pick this old style up one wonders

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the answer. I have found the problem. I have changed the where clause with this: `WHERE ex.ProductionOrderId = 4 and al.ProductionOrderId = 4`. Now it works without doing `Group by`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use only `DISTINCT` instead of `subquery`  :

```
select distinct (case when al.NumberEncoding = 3 
                      then RIGHT(ex.Serial,LEN(ex.Serial)-2) 
                      else RIGHT(ex.Serial,LEN(ex.Serial)-18)       
                  end) as Serial, AggregationLevel
from ExternalCode ex inner join 
     AggregationLevelConfiguration al
     on ex.AggregationLevel = al.AggregationLevelConfigurationId
where ex.ProductionOrderId = 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
       SELECT * FROM
        (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Serial ORDER BY Serial) AS Dup
        FROM
        (
        Select Serial = CASE al.NumberEncoding
                        WHEN 3 THEN RIGHT(ex.Serial,LEN(ex.Serial)-2) 
                        ELSE RIGHT(ex.Serial,LEN(ex.Serial)-18)       
                        END AS AggregationLevel
        FROM ExternalCode ex, AggregationLevelConfiguration al
        where ex.ProductionOrderId = 4 and 
        ex.AggregationLevel = al.AggregationLevelConfigurationId
        )dt
        )Fnl WHERE Dup=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:

```
SELECT Serial, AggregationLevel
FROM (
    SELECT
        CASE al.NumberEncoding
            WHEN 3 THEN RIGHT(ex.Serial,LEN(ex.Serial)-2) 
            ELSE RIGHT(ex.Serial,LEN(ex.Serial)-18)       
        END as Serial
    ,   AggregationLevel
    FROM ExternalCode ex
    JOIN AggregationLevelConfiguration al ON ex.AggregationLevel = al.AggregationLevelConfigurationId
    WHERE ex.ProductionOrderId = 4 and al.ProductionOrderId = 4
) nested
```

I have also added the constraint with `AggregationLevelConfiguration` and `ProductionOrderId`, without using `Group by`.